# htaccess password protection error

Tags: .htaccess

I have an HTACCESS as follows:

```
AuthUserFile /home/nasht00/.htmydomain
AuthName "EnterPassword"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

When I try it, the password pop-up appears. Whatever I enter in it, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

My password file is under /home/nasht00/.htmydomain .
Its owner is nasht00:www-data (nasht00 is my user, www-data is the group that apache2 belongs to). File permissions on that file is 775.

What am I missing?

If I try without the htaccess it works fine of course.

I have Ubuntu 9.10 with apache2.

Comment: The error log says...?

Comment: ahh .... Permission denied:                                Could not open password file: /home/nasht00/.htmydomain

Comment: what user/group should it be then??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user or group httpd is running as needs read access to the directories leading to the file in order to be able to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it, I'm not sure why but it works if I put my password file under "/var/www/". I kept the same user/group and permissions.